# mongo db querying array values with greater and less than

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a schema similar to

```
{
   'user_id' : 1,
   'marks' : [10, 40]
}
```

I want to find the number of users who have scored marks between 20 and 30 at least once.

I tried the following query

```
db.users.count({
   'marks' : {$gte: '20', $lt: '30'}
})
```

But this also included those with marks more than 30 ...

Comment: Exact duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038818/mongodb-query-to-match-each-element-in-doc-array-to-a-condition

Comment: thanks, i looked for similar questions but could not find one...

Comment: actually in your query you are using strings instead of numbers as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assuming you had the following data in collection scores:

```
{ 'user_id' : 1, 'marks' : [ 10, 40 ] }
{ 'user_id' : 2, 'marks' : [ 5, 18 ] }
{ 'user_id' : 3, 'marks' : [ 15, 25 ] }
{ 'user_id' : 4, 'marks' : [ 22, 33 ] }
```

Then you would expect to filter user_ids 3 and 4, a count of 2.

The simplest way to run your query is to do:

```
db.scores.count({'marks':{$in: [20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]}})
```

But not pretty...

Comment: yeah was thinking of not doing that. will accept this as there seems no other option

Answer (score 34):

Use [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) to constrain both parts of the range query to the *same* `marks` element:

```js
db.users.count({
    marks: {$elemMatch: {$gte: 20, $lt: 30}}
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Isn't it just this:

```
db.scores.count( { 'marks' : { '$gt' : min_value , '$lt' : max_value } } )
```

Which in your case would translate to:

```
db.scores.count( { 'marks' : { '$gt' : 20 , '$lt' : 30 } } )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
db.scores.count(
   { marks: { $elemMatch: { $gte: 20, $lt: 30} } }
)
```

For more information refer https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

Answer (score 1):

with $and you can also write

```
db.scores.count({$and: [{"price": {$lt: 30}}, {"price": {$gte: 20}}]})
```